# Is there an extension with Vim like folding support for sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3

If you fold text in vim and you try to delete the folded text with backspace the folded text opens. Is there an extension which sets the folding symbol in sublimetext read only?

Comment: is this a vim question or sublimetext question? I don't get you..

Comment: @Kent sublimetext question

Comment: Removing the vim tag, this has nothing to do with vim.